# If $L$ is elliptic, is $\partial_t - L$ hypoelliptic?

Tags: partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, differential-operators, elliptic-equations, elliptic-operators

If $L$ is the Beltrami Laplacian on $(M,g)$, then it is known that $P = \partial_t - L$ is hypoelliptic. Can the same be said in general, when $L$ is arbitrary elliptic (of order $2$, if it helps)? Is it possible to draw conclusions about hypoellipticity by looking at the symbol of the operator? (For simplicity, I consider $L$ to act on complex-valued functions, not on sections in arbitrary vector bundles.)

Answer (score 0):

No, the Schrödinger operator $i\Delta$ is a counterexample. If you assume that $L$ is self-adjoint (and some technical assumptions) then you get that $L$ generates an analytic semigroup and therefore $e^{-tL}$ is smoothing. For details see for instance the book by Renardy and Rogers.

Comment: $\Bbb e ^{-tL}$ is smoothing only on its domain of definition, which is $L^2$. How would this imply hypoellipticity?

Comment: Say, $L$ is a (pseudo-)differential operator of order $\geq 1$, then $[L, e^{-tL}] = 0$ and you can use elliptic regularity to get any (negative) Sobolev regularity.